# Flat torsionfree connection in Kähler manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, connections

If $\nabla$ is a flat torsionfree connection and $J$ is a complex structure, we define
\begin{align}
d^{\nabla}J(X,Y)=(\nabla_{X}J)Y-(\nabla_{Y}J)X.
\end{align}
Why flatness of $\nabla$ means $d^{\nabla}=0$, and $\nabla$ is torsionfree means $(d^{\nabla })^{2}(\mathrm{id})=0$?

Comment: What is the source where these meanings are used? Looks like a typo. Usually, $d^{\nabla} Id$ can be interpreted as the torsion of $\nabla$, and $d^{\nabla} \circ d^{\nabla}$ is the curvature...

Comment: I found it in this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9712042 on page 4. So $d^{\nabla}(X,Y)=\nabla_{X}Y-\nabla_{Y}X-[X,Y]$?

Comment: I'm afraid that in your last equation you have made a typo again. I posted an answer hoping that it may clarify the things to you.

Comment: The formula for $\mathrm{d}^{\nabla} J$ that you give in the question holds only for torsion free connections. I have added this point to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer.** In general (see the extended answer), the formula for $\mathrm{d}^{\nabla} J$ would be
$$
d^{\nabla}J(X,Y)=\nabla_{X} \left( J(Y) \right) - \nabla_{Y} \left( J(X) \right) - J([X,Y])
$$
because the *almost complex structure* $J \colon TM \to TM$ is regarded as a $TM$-valued $1$-form (it has to satisfy $J^2 = - \mathrm{id}$ but this is irrelevant for the question we consider).

*Torsion free* means $T^{\nabla} = \mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \mathrm{id} = 0$, see equation (1.4) in the [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9712042) you mention.

*Flat* means $R^{\nabla} = \mathrm{d}^2_{\nabla} = \mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \circ \mathrm{d}^{\nabla} = 0$, see the cited [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9712042), next line after equation (1.3)

Now, when the connection $\nabla$ is torsion free, we can use the fact that in this case the *Lie bracket* is expressed simply as
$$
[X,Y] = \nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X
$$
and using (see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53887/covariant-derivative-of-1-1-tensor)) the notation
$$
(\nabla_X J) Y := \nabla_X (J(Y)) - J(\nabla_X Y)
$$
the general expression for $\mathrm{d}^{\nabla} J$ is simplified to
$$
\mathrm{d}^{\nabla} J (X,Y) = (\nabla_X J) Y - (\nabla_Y J) X
$$
as it is given, for instance, in this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9910091), Remark 1 on p.5.

**Extended answer.**

The invariant formula
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d} \omega(X_0,...,X_k) = & \sum_{0 \le i \le k}(-1)^{i} X_i \left(\omega(X_0, \ldots, \hat{X_i}, \ldots, X_k)\right) \\ 
& +\sum_{0 \le i<j \le k}(-1)^{i+j} \omega([X_i, X_j], X_0, \ldots, \hat{X_i}, \ldots, \hat{X_j}, \ldots, X_k)
\end{align}
$$
for the exterior derivative of a $k$-form $\omega \in \Omega^k(M)$ on a manifold $M$ can be used as a definition, and also it can be extended to $k$-forms with values in a vector bundle $E \to M$ almost without a change (formally):
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \omega(X_0,...,X_k) = & \sum_{0 \le i \le k}(-1)^{i} \nabla_{X_i} \left(\omega(X_0, \ldots, \hat{X_i}, \ldots, X_k)\right) \\ 
& +\sum_{0 \le i<j \le k}(-1)^{i+j} \omega([X_i, X_j], X_0, \ldots, \hat{X_i}, \ldots, \hat{X_j}, \ldots, X_k)
\end{align}
$$
where $\nabla \colon \Omega^0(E) \to \Omega^1(E)$ is a connection in vector bundle $E$.

Now let us make a few applications of this formula to the most basic cases.

For $\omega \in \Omega^0(E) \equiv \Gamma(E)$ we have $\mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \omega (X) = \nabla_X \omega$

When $\omega \in \Omega^1(E) \equiv \Omega^1(M) \otimes \Gamma(E)$ one gets
$$
\mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \omega (X,Y) = \nabla_X \omega(Y) - \nabla_Y \omega(X) - \omega([X,Y]) \tag{*}
$$

The identity map $\mathrm{id} \colon TM \to TM$ can be naturally seen as a $TM$-valued $1$-form, and the latter identity applied to it reads as
$$
\mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \mathrm{id} (X,Y) = \nabla_X Y - \nabla_Y X - [X,Y]
$$
where on the right hand side we see what is known as the **torsion** $T(X,Y) = T^{\nabla}(X,Y)$ of the connection $\nabla$

No surprise that **torsion free** ($T^{\nabla}(X,Y) = 0$) connections are in favour: we would like that the identity map has zero derivative!

Let us turn to the connection $\nabla$ itself. For $\omega \in \Omega^0(E)$ we regard  $\mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \omega = \nabla \omega$ as a $E$-valued $1$-form, and so we can use the identity (*) again:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \omega & = \nabla_X \mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \omega(Y) - \nabla_Y \mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \omega (X) - \mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \omega([X,Y]) \\
& = \nabla_X \nabla_Y \omega - \nabla_Y \nabla_X \omega - \nabla_{[X,Y]} \omega
\end{align}
$$
and again we recognize in RHS the **curvature operator** $R_{X Y}$ acting on a section $\omega \in \Gamma(E)$ of a vector bundle $E$ with a connection $\nabla$

Informally speaking, $\mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \circ \mathrm{d}^{\nabla} = R^{\nabla}$

A connection is called **flat** if $R^{\nabla} = \mathrm{d}^{\nabla} \circ \mathrm{d}^{\nabla} = 0$

We like flat connections because the derivatives commute nicely.

This is precisely the story that can be read off from the equation (1.3) in the cited [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9712042)

All this is, indeed, very standard stuff. A more detailed treatment with everything made precise one can find e.g. in **I.Madsen, J.Torenhave** "[From Calculus to Cohomology](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=CwQ-L9MOGUwC&hl=en)".

For a gentle introduction I would recommend the Wikipedia's [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) and the references therein (especially the book of **R.W.R. Darling** "[Differential forms and connections](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=TdCaahMK0z4C)").

Of course, all this is usually mentioned in the books and lectures on Kähler geometry in the sections on background. See, for instance, **W.Ballmann**'s "[Lectures on Kähler Manifolds](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/kaehler0609.pdf)", p.4.